# how to use uglifyjs to minimize reactJS+requireJS

Tags: reactjs, requirejs, uglifyjs

Recently, I have integrated reactJS into our current backbone/requireJS application. the solution I am using is through JSXTransformer, so I can load reactJS component easily inside backbone like below:

```
var CreateQuoteMainComp = require('jsx!MyComp');
ReactDOM.render(React.createFactory(MyComp)(),
                document.getElementById('myComp'));
```

This solution is very good to make sure reactJS to be working with requireJS together. But I found one small issue, that is to minimization of the code:
In minimized js (production env). I found this warning in the console:

```
Warning: It looks like you're using a minified copy of the development build of React
You are currently using minified code outside of NODE_ENV === 'production'...
```

I am using grunt to minimize the code, this is the config part:

```
requirejs: {
      desktopJS: {
        options: {
          baseUrl: 'public/js/app',
          wrap: true,
          name: '../libs/almond',
          preserveLicenseComments: false,
          optimize: 'uglify',
          mainConfigFile: 'public/js/app/config/config.js',
          insertRequire: ['init/DesktopInit'],
          include: ['config/config', 'init/DesktopInit'],
          out: 'public/build/desktop/main.min.js'
        }
      }
    },
```

Can anyone help to point out in order to package reactJS part inside requireJS, how can I config uglify? I checked FB website, but there is NO mentioning for this solution, they only give using react cli to minimize

Thanks in advance.